# PYODBC and not continuing while loop during TRY CATCH within stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, odbc

I'm at an absolute loss and need help please

I can run this query no problem in SQL Management Studio.

It returns exactly what I want. The BatchID from the import.

However the moment i start running this in python it returns an error

"[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements."

or

[Execution failed on sql 'EXEC [CHAMP_DW].[dbo].[ETL_stage_evestment_performance_to_champ]': ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name '#stagingPerformance'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW)")"

Does anybody see anything wrong in this SQL

**Example Works in bash**

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P 'Password' -Q "EXEC [CHAMP_DW].[dbo].[ETL_stage_evestment_performance_to_champ];"
```

**Fails message and only 1 row exectuted**

```
my_conn.execute("EXEC [CHAMP_DW].[dbo].[ETL_stage_evestment_performance_to_champ]")
```

Its a pretty simple TRY CATCH with some Validation

```html
USE [CHAMP_DW]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[ETL_stage_evestment_performance_to_champ]    Script Date: 21/02/2019 4:48:37 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ETL_stage_evestment_performance_to_champ]

AS
BEGIN
 
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
 SET XACT_ABORT ON; --> the only change

 /*Variable Declaration*/

 DECLARE @BatchImportID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

 DECLARE
  @FileProcessedDate DATETIME,
  @FileProcessedUTCDate DATETIME,
  @ImportStatus TINYINT,
  @ErrorCode VARCHAR(2000),
  @ErrorMessage VARCHAR(4000),
  @StagingID int,
  @value_date varchar(255),
  @firm_id varchar(255),  
  @product_id varchar(255),
  @vehicle_id varchar(255),
  @ccy varchar(255),
  @reporting_method varchar(255),
  @performance_return varchar(255),
  @log_return varchar(255)

 /*Assign static value for whole one time process*/

 SELECT
  @BatchImportID = NEWID(),
  @FileProcessedDate = GETDATE(),
  @FileProcessedUTCDate = GETUTCDATE()

 /*Create staging table so we can re-run procedure instead of having to rerun complete task again and again*/

  CREATE TABLE #stagingPerformance
  (
   [index] [bigint] NULL,
   [value_date] [datetime] NULL,      
   [firm_id] [bigint] NULL,
   [ccy] [varchar](max) NULL,
   [product_id] [bigint] NULL,
   [reporting_method] [varchar](max) NULL,
   [vehicle_id]  [bigint] NULL,
   [performance_return] [float] NULL,
   [log_return] [float] NULL
  )

  CREATE INDEX [IX_EvestmentData_1] ON #stagingPerformance
  (
   [index] ASC,
   [value_date] ASC,
   [firm_id] ASC
  )

  -- POPULATE TEMP TABLE

 INSERT INTO #stagingPerformance
  SELECT TOP 50 a.[index], a.value_date, a.firm_id, a.ccy, 
   a.product_id, a.reporting_method, a.vehicle_id, a.performance_return, a.log_return
  FROM CHAMP_DW.dbo.champ_dw_staging_evestment_performance a
  --WHERE a.reporting_method<>'Index'


 /*While loop started to get process record one by one*/

 WHILE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM #stagingPerformance AS FHD WITH (NOLOCK))
 BEGIN
  
  BEGIN TRY
   
   BEGIN TRANSACTION

   /*To assign 1 record values to respective variables*/

   SELECT TOP 1
    @StagingID = FHD.[index],
    @firm_id = NULLIF(FHD.[firm_id],''),
    @product_id = NULLIF(FHD.[product_id],''),
    @vehicle_id = NULLIF(FHD.[vehicle_id],''),
    @value_date = NULLIF(FHD.[value_date],''),
    @reporting_method = NULLIF(FHD.[reporting_method],''),    
    @ccy = NULLIF(FHD.[ccy],''),    
    @performance_return = NULLIF(FHD.[performance_return],''),
    @log_return = NULLIF(FHD.[log_return],'')    
   FROM #stagingPerformance AS FHD WITH (NOLOCK)
   --WHERE reporting_method <> 'Index'
   ORDER BY FHD.[index]

   /*Record wise validation start*/

   IF @firm_id IS NULL BEGIN
    SELECT
     @ErrorCode = ISNULL(@ErrorCode,'') + ',' + '101',
     @ErrorMessage = ISNULL(@ErrorMessage,'') + ',' + 'Firm ID is required.'
   END

   IF @product_id IS NULL BEGIN
    SELECT
     @ErrorCode = ISNULL(@ErrorCode,'') + ',' + '102',
     @ErrorMessage = ISNULL(@ErrorMessage,'') + ',' + 'Product ID is required.'
   END

   IF @value_date IS NULL BEGIN
    SELECT
     @ErrorCode = ISNULL(@ErrorCode,'') + ',' + '103',
     @ErrorMessage = ISNULL(@ErrorMessage,'') + ',' + 'Value Date is required.'
   END

   IF @reporting_method IS NULL BEGIN
    SELECT
     @ErrorCode = ISNULL(@ErrorCode,'') + ',' + '104',
     @ErrorMessage = ISNULL(@ErrorMessage,'') + ',' + 'Reporting Method is required.'
   END

   
   IF @reporting_method IS NOT NULL AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 WHERE @reporting_method in ('Gross', 'Net', 'Index')) BEGIN
    SELECT
     @ErrorCode = ISNULL(@ErrorCode,'') + ',' + '115',
     @ErrorMessage = ISNULL(@ErrorMessage,'') + ',' + 'Reporting Method is invalid'
   END


   IF @ccy IS NULL BEGIN
    SELECT
     @ErrorCode = ISNULL(@ErrorCode,'') + ',' + '105',
     @ErrorMessage = ISNULL(@ErrorMessage,'') + ',' + 'ccy is required.'
   END

   IF @value_date IS NOT NULL AND ISDATE(@value_date) = 0 BEGIN
    SELECT
     @ErrorCode = ISNULL(@ErrorCode,'') + ',' + '106',
     @ErrorMessage = ISNULL(@ErrorMessage,'') + ',' + 'Invalid value of Value Date.'
   END

   IF @performance_return IS NOT NULL AND ISNUMERIC(@performance_return) = 0 BEGIN
    SELECT
     @ErrorCode = ISNULL(@ErrorCode,'') + CASE WHEN @ErrorCode LIKE '%112%' THEN '' ELSE ',' + '112' END,
     @ErrorMessage = ISNULL(@ErrorMessage,'') + ',' + 'Invalid value of performance.'
   END

   IF @log_return IS NOT NULL AND ISNUMERIC(@log_return) = 0 BEGIN
    SELECT
     @ErrorCode = ISNULL(@ErrorCode,'') + CASE WHEN @ErrorCode LIKE '%112%' THEN '' ELSE ',' + '112' END,
     @ErrorMessage = ISNULL(@ErrorMessage,'') + ',' + 'Invalid value of log_return.'
   END


   IF @firm_id IS NOT NULL AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM CHAMP_DW.dbo.champ_dw_fund_manager_mapping AS DFM WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE DFM.evestment_fund_manager_id = @firm_id)

   BEGIN
    SELECT
     @ErrorCode = ISNULL(@ErrorCode,'') + ',' + '113',
     @ErrorMessage = ISNULL(@ErrorMessage,'') + ',' + 'Firm ID is not Mapped'
   END

   IF @product_id IS NOT NULL AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.champ_dw_product_mapping AS DAM WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE DAM.evestment_product_id =@product_id)
   BEGIN
    SELECT
     @ErrorCode = ISNULL(@ErrorCode,'') + ',' + '114',
     @ErrorMessage = ISNULL(@ErrorMessage,'') + ',' + 'Product ID is not Mapped'
   END

   IF @ccy IS NOT NULL AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].champ_dw_dim_currency AS DC WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE DC.currency = @ccy) BEGIN
    SELECT
     @ErrorCode = ISNULL(@ErrorCode,'') + ',' + '112',
     @ErrorMessage = ISNULL(@ErrorMessage,'') + ',' + 'ccy is not found in DIM_ccy.'
   END

   SELECT
    @ErrorCode = NULLIF(STUFF(@ErrorCode,1,1,''),''),
    @ErrorMessage = NULLIF(STUFF(@ErrorMessage,1,1,''),'')

   IF @ErrorMessage IS NOT NULL
   BEGIN
    ;THROW 50552,'VALIDATION RAISE ERROR.',1
   END

   /*Record wise validation end*/

   /*To get unique record value based on FundID, AssetID, AsAtDate columns*/

   DECLARE
    @performance_id INT = 0,
    @vfirm_id INT,
    @vproduct_id INT,
    @vvehicle_id INT,
    @vvalue_date datetime2,
    @vreporting_method nvarchar(max),
    @vccy nvarchar(3),
    @vperformance_return float,
    @vlog_return float,    
    @map_firm_id INT,
    @map_product_id INT

   SELECT
    @vfirm_id = TRY_PARSE(@firm_id AS INT),
    @vproduct_id = TRY_PARSE(@product_id AS INT),
    @vvehicle_id = TRY_PARSE(@vehicle_id AS INT),
    @vvalue_date = TRY_PARSE(@value_date AS datetime2),
    @vreporting_method = @reporting_method,
    @vccy = cast(@ccy as nvarchar(3)),
    @vperformance_return = TRY_PARSE(@performance_return AS float),
    @vlog_return = TRY_PARSE(@log_return AS float)
   
   SELECT @map_firm_id = (SELECT fund_manager_mapping_id FROM CHAMP_DW.dbo.champ_dw_fund_manager_mapping fm WHERE fm.evestment_fund_manager_id = @vfirm_id)
   
   SELECT @map_product_id = (SELECT product_mapping_id FROM CHAMP_DW.dbo.champ_dw_product_mapping fp  WHERE fp.product_mapping_id=@vvehicle_id)
   -- changing to vehicle mapping
   --SELECT @map_product_id = (SELECT product_mapping_id FROM CHAMP_DW.dbo.champ_dw_product_mapping fp  WHERE fp.evestment_vehicle_id=@vvehicle_id)
   
   SELECT 
    @performance_id = FFHD.performance_id 
   FROM dbo.[champ_dw_fact_performance] AS FFHD WITH (NOLOCK)
   WHERE FFHD.fund_manager_id = @map_firm_id
    AND FFHD.product_id = @map_product_id
    AND FFHD.value_date = @vvalue_date
    AND FFHD.data_source = 'eVestment'
    AND FFHD.ccy_id = @vccy
    AND FFHD.reporting_method = @vreporting_method

   /*Update record, if any value has different then already exist in DB.*/

   UPDATE FFHD
   SET 
    FFHD.ccy_id = @ccy,
    FFHD.performance_return = @vperformance_return,
    FFHD.log_return = @vlog_return   
   FROM dbo.[champ_dw_fact_performance] AS FFHD WITH (NOLOCK)
   WHERE FFHD.performance_id = @performance_id
   AND
   (
    ISNULL(FFHD.performance_return,'0') <> @vperformance_return
    OR
    ISNULL(FFHD.log_return,'0') <> @vlog_return
   )

   /*Add new record if record is not found based on FundID, AssetID, AsAtDate columns*/

   INSERT INTO dbo.[champ_dw_fact_performance]
   (
    value_date,
    reporting_method,
    valuation_quality,
    data_source,
    performance_return,
    log_return,
    ccy_id,
    fund_manager_id,
    product_id    
   )
   SELECT
    @vvalue_date AS value_date,
    @vreporting_method AS reporting_method,
    'Actual' as valuation_quality,
    'eVestment' as data_source,
    @vperformance_return AS performance_return,
    @vlog_return AS log_return,
    @vccy AS ccy_id,
    @map_firm_id AS fund_manager_id_id,
    @map_product_id AS product_id_id
   WHERE NOT EXISTS
   (
    SELECT
     1
    FROM dbo.[champ_dw_fact_performance] AS FFHD WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE FFHD.fund_manager_id = @map_firm_id
    AND FFHD.product_id = @map_product_id
    AND FFHD.value_date = @vvalue_date
    AND FFHD.data_source = 'eVestment'
    AND FFHD.ccy_id = @vccy
    AND FFHD.reporting_method = @vreporting_method
   )

   --/*To add success record in log table*/

   INSERT INTO dbo.[champ_dw_fact_performance_log]
   (   BatchImportID,
    FileProcessedDate,
    FileProcessedUTCDate,
    ImportStatus,
    ErrorCode,
    ErrorMessage,
    StagingID,
    value_date,
    reporting_method,
    valuation_quality,
    data_source,
    ccy_id,
    performance_return,
    log_return,
    firm_id,
    product_id,
    vehicle_id
   )
   SELECT
    @BatchImportID AS BatchImportID,    
    @FileProcessedDate AS FileProcessedDate,
    @FileProcessedUTCDate AS FileProcessedUTCDate,
    1 AS ImportStatus,
    '100' AS ErrorCode,
    'Success' AS ErrorMessage,
    @StagingID AS StagingID,
    @value_date AS value_date,
    @reporting_method AS reporting_method,
    'Actual' AS valuation_quality,
    'eVestment' AS data_source,
    @ccy AS ccy_id,
    @performance_return AS performance_return,
    @log_return AS log_return,
    @firm_id AS firm_id,
    @product_id AS product_id,
    @vehicle_id AS vehicle_id   
    
   COMMIT TRANSACTION

  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
   
   IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK
   --BEGIN
   -- ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
   --END

   DECLARE
    @ERROR_MESSAGE NVARCHAR(4000)

   SELECT
    @ERROR_MESSAGE = ERROR_MESSAGE()

   IF @ERROR_MESSAGE <> 'VALIDATION RAISE ERROR.'
   BEGIN
    SELECT
     @ErrorCode = ISNULL(@ErrorCode,'') + CASE WHEN ISNULL(@ERROR_MESSAGE,'') <> '' THEN ',' + '999' ELSE '' END,
     @ErrorMessage = ISNULL(@ErrorMessage,'') + CASE WHEN ISNULL(@ERROR_MESSAGE,'') <> '' THEN ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4000),@ERROR_MESSAGE) ELSE '' END
   END

   SELECT
    @ErrorCode = NULLIF(CASE WHEN @ErrorCode LIKE '%999%' THEN STUFF(@ErrorCode,1,1,'') ELSE @ErrorCode END,''),
    @ErrorMessage = NULLIF(CASE WHEN @ErrorCode LIKE '%999%' THEN STUFF(@ErrorMessage,1,1,'') ELSE @ErrorMessage END,'')

   /*To add failed record in log table*/

   INSERT INTO dbo.[champ_dw_fact_performance_log]
   (
    BatchImportID,
    FileProcessedDate,
    FileProcessedUTCDate,
    ImportStatus,
    ErrorCode,
    ErrorMessage,
    StagingID,
    value_date,
    reporting_method,
    valuation_quality,
    data_source,
    ccy_id,
    performance_return,
    log_return,
    firm_id,
    product_id,
    vehicle_id
   )
   SELECT
    @BatchImportID AS BatchImportID,
    @FileProcessedDate AS FileProcessedDate,
    @FileProcessedUTCDate AS FileProcessedUTCDate,
    0 AS ImportStatus,
    @ErrorCode AS ErrorCode,
    @ErrorMessage AS ErrorMessage,
    @StagingID AS StagingID,
    @value_date AS value_date,
    @reporting_method AS reporting_method,
    'Actual' AS valuation_quality,
    'eVestment' AS data_source,
    @ccy AS ccy_id,
    @performance_return AS performance_return,
    @log_return AS log_return,
    @firm_id AS firm_id,
    @product_id AS product_id,
    @vehicle_id AS vehicle_id

  END CATCH


  DELETE FHD
  FROM #stagingPerformance AS FHD
  WHERE FHD.[index] = @StagingID

  SELECT
   @firm_id = NULL,
   @product_id = NULL,
   @vehicle_id = NULL,
   @value_date = NULL,
   @reporting_method = NULL,
   @ccy = NULL,
   @performance_return = NULL,
   @log_return = NULL,
   @ImportStatus = NULL,
   @ErrorCode = NULL,
   @ErrorMessage = NULL

 END

 SELECT @BatchImportID as 'BatchID'

 
 DROP TABLE #stagingPerformance
 
 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

This type of problem always happen to me whenever there is an outside BEGIN TRAN.  Meaning the caller of the stored procedure has a BEGIN TRAN as well.   Because when you do a rollback, the outside caller also needs to check if there is still a open connection to commit.  So the outside caller prior rollback or commit must check if there is still an open connection.

Based on my experience, you can only ROLLBACK once.  And @@TRANCOUNT is set to zero.

Proof:

1) Works - multiple commits

```
BEGIN TRAN
    BEGIN TRAN
    COMMIT TRAN
COMMIT TRAN
```

2) Does not work - rollback at the middle

```
BEGIN TRAN
    BEGIN TRAN
    ROLLBACK TRAN
COMMIT TRAN
```

3) Correct commit at the end - checks if transaction still exists.

```
BEGIN TRAN
    BEGIN TRAN
    ROLLBACK TRAN

IF (@@TRANCOUNT>0)
COMMIT TRAN
```

At the very least, i recommend all your commits and rollbacks check @@TRANCOUNT>0.

Comment: Thank Earl, does this work with TRY CATCH? and then entering into a logging table?

Comment: @RachOdwyer You can use a table variable to store the data for logging then perform the log after the rollback.  Table variables survive after a rollback.     https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/52258/Three-Really-Handy-Tricks-With-SQL-Server-Table-Va